# What is the difference between ServiceBusSenderClient and ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

I want to know the difference between SenderClient and AsynSenderClient in Azure Service Bus. What is the difference in the below 2 code snippets?

*Snippet 1:*

```
ServiceBusSenderClient sender = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
    .connectionString("<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE SERVICE BUS NAMESPACE >>")
    .sender()
    .queueName("<< QUEUE NAME >>")
    .buildClient();
```

*Snippet 2:*

```
ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient sender = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
    .connectionString("<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE SERVICE BUS NAMESPACE >>")
    .sender()
    .queueName("<< QUEUE NAME >>")
    .buildAsyncClient();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ServiceBusClientBuilder` is used to create a `ServiceBusSenderClient` instance. The `buildClient()` method is invoked to build the client. The resulting `sender` variable is of type `ServiceBusSenderClient`, which provides a **synchronous** programming model for sending messages to the Service Bus queue specified by the `queue`.
- When you use `ServiceBusSenderClient` to send a message, the calling thread will be blocked until the message is sent and a response is received from the Service Bus service.

If you use maven dependency please check as given below.

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Azure Messaging Service Bus -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Azure Identity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.identity</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Azure Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Azure Logging Dependencies (optional) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-core-logger-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here you can explore more content for your requirement.
**[ServiceBusSenderClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-dotnet)**

**Here is the asynchronous approach:**

- `ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient` is an asynchronous client that provides non-blocking methods for sending messages to a Service Bus entity.
- In Java,  `ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient` class extends the `java.lang.Object` class, which is the root of the class hierarchy. That means `ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient`  will inherits the basic functionalities provided by the `java.lang.Object` class, such as the `toString()`, `hashCode()`, and `equals()` methods.

I tried a sample application use the `ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient` class to send a message to a Service Bus entity asynchronously. For the dependencies check above.

```java
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage;

public class ServiceBusSenderExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance of the ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient
        ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient senderClient = new ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient("<connectionString>", "<queueOrTopicName>");

        // Create a message
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello, Service Bus!");

        // Send the message asynchronously
        senderClient.sendMessage(message).subscribe(
            messageId -> {
                System.out.println("Message sent successfully. MessageId: " + messageId);
            },
            error -> {
                System.err.println("Error occurred while sending the message: " + error);
            },
            () -> {
                System.out.println("Message sending complete.");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

- Non-blocking behavior and want to leverage the benefits of asynchronous programming, you can use [`ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussenderasyncclient?view=azure-java-stable) check on the link for more information.